# How to use Python unittest assertRaises to test that function doesn't throws any exception?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions

I'm trying to test if some function DOES NOT throws any exception, using the unittest module.
Is this possible? I only know about the assertRaises method, but this one just test for thrown exceptions, and a None argument won't work for the Exception type argument...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So just call the function and if it raise an exception it will be reported as an ERROR not a failure which mean your unittest runner will stop (no way to continue it), if you want to report it as a Failure you can do like this:

```
try:
   somefunction()
except:
   self.fail("....")
```

Comment: so I guess there's no cleaner way to achieve this, but by adding trys/excepts or letting it report ERRORs... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If an exception occurs the test will be marked as failed, so I don't see why you need to actually assert anything. If you really want to, you can always just do it yourself:

```
try:
   foo()
except:
   raise AssertionError('should not raise exception')
```

Comment: I usually don't bother with `try`/`except`, and just add a comment at the bottom of the test method like `# this test passes as long as no exceptions are raised`

Comment: well, in fact if an exception occurs, it will be marked as an ERROR, but you are right, it is marked anyway. Just was wondering if there is a cleaner way to test this without additional code (trys/excepts) and no ERRORS. Guess not...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem for my unit tests. mouad & Michael are correct, but for cleaner way to handle assertion for exception with consistent method.

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertNoRaise(self, callableObj):
        try:
            callableObj()
        except:
            raise AssertionError('shouldn\'t raise an exception')

    def assertAnyRaise(self, callableObj):
        try:
            callableObj()
        except:
            return
        raise AssertionError('should raise an exception')
```

or seperate above class from inheritance, and do mixin with unittest.TestCase. either way would work

and a use case

```
class my_test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_assertion(self):
        self.assertAnyRaise(lambda: 1+'a')
        self.assertNoRaise(lambda: 1+1)
```

please excuse my bad english.